# How to handle floats with sympy?

Tags: floating-point, sympy

This is some dialogue that I had with python using `ipython`

```
In [1]: from sympy import symbols                                                                

In [2]: a,b,c,d,e = symbols('a b c d e')                                                         

In [3]: expr = a*b*c*d - e                                                                       

In [4]: expr.subs({'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':'.1', 'e':'2.4'})                                    
Out[4]: 4.44089209850063e-16
```

How to get `0` there?

---

I tried this and works:

```
from sympy import symbols
from fractions import Fraction
a,b,c,d,e = symbols('a b c d e')
expr = a*b*c*d - e
expr.subs({'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':Fraction('.1'), 'e':'2.4'})

Out: 0

expr.subs({'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':Fraction('.1'), 'e':'2.4'}) == 0

True
```

**Question:  Any quirks/gotchas with Fraction(...) approach?**

Comment: Well, only decimal numbers which can be written as a sum of perfect powers of 2 can have a precise representation as binary floating point. Nor 0.1 nor 2.4 fulfil this requirement, so they are necessarily approximated. If you want exact results, fractions are the way to go. Quirks might be that things can get slow for complicated expressions, especially if you want to evaluate lots of them.

Comment: Voters: Let's not close this as a duplicate of "is floating point math broken", mmkay?

Answer (score 2):

Rational('.1') will create an exact SymPy fraction for you. But `nsimplify` can accept a variety of containers and change any decimals to Rationals when the flag `rational` is set to True:

```
>>> reps
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': '.1', 'e': '2.4'}
>>> nsimplify(reps, rational=True)
{a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 1/10, e: 12/5}
>>> sympify('a*b*c*d - e').subs(_)
0
```